# Regex: Find those html pages which does not contain this particular word on a link

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have these 2 lines on more than 3000 HTML pages:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://mywebsite.com/hi/about.html" />
```

and

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://mywebsite.com/about.html" />
```

So, I want to find with regex all those pages that contain those lines which DO NOT contain this word `hi` from the `/hi/` link.

Comment: Is `hi` always between `mywebsite.com/` and `/about.html` or can it be anywhere in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `/hi/` is always after `https://mywebsite.com` you can use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure you exclude those matches. In that case,

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/(?!hi\/)
```

might work for you ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/REFDS8/1)). The first part is just a literal match (the backslashes are necessary for escaping, IIRC) and the `(?!hi\/)` is the negative lookahead: it makes sure the `hi\/` does not occur. But Regex101 does a better job of explain the regex than I can.

<sub>(I assume you're familiar with the Notepad++ capabilities for mass search, but if not, [this link](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-use-the-find-in-files-feature-in-notepad.html) may help.)</sub>